# Azure pipeline remote powershell task hanging

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I try the "run powershell on remote machines" task to restart my Tomcat (java) service on the Windows server.
It just keep printing useless info in the console (target machine name)

Here is the detail about the powershell script:

1. stop Tomcat service (call a .bat file)
2. move .jar files to right location & replace old files
3. start Tomcat service (call a .bat file)

```sh
& D:\MY\PATH\stop.bat;
......
Copy-Item -Path "D:/s-1.0.jar" -Destination $sqs_path -Force;
......
& D:\MY\PATH\start.bat;
```

When I run the same command directly in target windows server, the "powershell part" trigger .bat script job, then get back to powershell console successfully .
Later, a new window pops out. The new window is Tomcat server that shows logs of my service.

However, when I do the same job with Azure release pipeline, the Tomcat window did not show up in target machine.
And release job console keep hanging (just print the name of targer machine).
I guess somewhat the output of popout window has be redirected to the console in release pipeline.

In addition, if I cancel the release job. my Tomcat service still working. (just without console to debug)

Or, another thought, can I achieve my goal with other 'task' in release pipeline? (powershell is not a "must")

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

**[Update1]**
I change the service start commamd to run the .bat in another window.

```sh
& D:\MY\PATH\stop.bat;
......
Copy-Item -Path "D:/s-1.0.jar" -Destination $sqs_path -Force;
......
Start-Process cmd.exe -ArgumentList "/C D:\sources\SQS.Dev\start.bat;"
```

And it turns out "nothing happens" ...
The remote powershell task finish immediately.

Answer (score 0):

The [**PowerShell on Target Machines task**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/powershell-on-target-machines?view=azure-devops) uses [**WinRM**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winrm/portal) to connect and access the remote target machine.

Normally, **WinRM** requires the agent machine and the remote target machine have been joined into the same domain or workgroup.

Please check with the following things:

1. Ensure the agent machine and the remote target machine have been joined into the same domain or workgroup.
2. Ensure you have followed the steps [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/apps/cd/deploy-webdeploy-iis-winrm?view=azure-devops#winrm-configuration) to configure the WinRM.
3. If you have configured the WinRM. Login to the agent machine, ensure you can connect and access the remote target machine when you manually try to call the remote PowerShell. You can try with the following script on the agent machine to test if the WinRM can work well to connect and access the remote target machine.

   ```
   Param(
     # The IP address or FQDN of the remote machine
     [string]$computerIp = "{computerIp}"
   )

   # Username and Password of the admin account on the remote machine
   $Username = "{Username}"
   $Password = ConvertTo-SecureString "{Password}" -AsPlainText -Force
   $cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($Username,$password)

   # Call the remote PowerShell script
   Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computerIp -Credential $cred -ErrorAction Stop -ScriptBlock {Invoke-Expression -Command:"powershell.exe /c '{absolute path of the remote PowerShell script}'"}
   ```

   - If it does not work when you try manually calling the remote PowerShell script on the agent machine, the task in the pipeline of course is not able to work. The issue should be on the WinRM, maybe, the WinRM is not configured well.
   - If it work well when you manually try on the the agent machine, the issue should be on the self-hosted agent. Try to set up a new self-hosted agent with the admin account to see if it can work.

**[UPDATE]**

As I mentioned above, please try manually calling the remote PowerShell script on the agent machine to see if the commands for '**`start Tomcat service`**' can work.
The **PowerShell on Target Machines task** is running on the agent machine. If the remote PowerShell script cannot work as expected when you manually try it on the agent machine, it is of course not able to work on the task in pipeline.

At this time, the possible reason of the issue could be the following:

- The connection between the machines has some problems.
- The PowerShell script has some issues. Maybe you missed some settings for remoting call the script.

Comment: If I understand your comment right, you are talking about setting up the connection between agent&remote machine. However, in my case. "stop tomcat service", "replace .jar files" work as expected. The problem is "how to start tomcat service"

Comment: Hi @hanshih, I have updated my answer with more explanations and suggestions. Please check it.

Comment: Thank for your update. In my case, I run the pipeline with built-in agent (with monthly 1800 min quota). In that case, how can I perform the tests mentioned in your update?